# Hadoop Resource Manager not starting

Tags: java, hadoop, client, ipc, resourcemanager

I am new to Hadoop so I started setting up partially distributed Hadoop cluster on `localhost`. I created a wordcount program jar to run but when I run this jar the following error is shown for nine times:

```
NFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9040. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

Also when I type jps command my services started are:

```
9154 DataNode

9777 NodeManager

8967 NameNode

9441 SecondaryNameNode

10060 Jps
```

**core-site.xml**

```
<configuration>

  <property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  </property>

  <property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/usr/local/hadoop/tmp</value>
  <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
  </property>

  <property>
     <name>fs.file.impl</name>
     <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem</value>
     <description>The FileSystem for file: uris.</description>
  </property>
  -
  <property>
     <name>fs.hdfs.impl</name>
     <value>org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem</value>
     <description>The FileSystem for hdfs: uris.</description>
  </property>

</configuration>
```

**yarn-site.xml**

```
<configuration>

  <!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
    <value>localhost:9025</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
    <value>localhost:9030</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
    <value>localhost:9040</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.address</name>
    <value>localhost:9050</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.localizer.address</name>
    <value>localhost:9060</value>
  </property>

</configuration>
```

**mapred-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>localhost:8021</value>
  </property>

</configuration>
```

Help appreciated. How do I resolve this ??

Comment: Check what's going on in the ResourceManger's log file.

Comment: Check if your Java version is compatible with your Hadoop Version. Latest Hadoop 3.1.1 supports Java 8

Answer (score 6):

The most probable reason for no ResourceManager daemon would be an error in HTTP port binding. Go through the log files of yarn-resourcemanager-*. You can easily find the cause of error.

Comment: The log file to look at is $HADOOP_HOME/logs/yarn-rdmaHB-resourcemanager-(yourhostname).log